# Can we add Meta badges to flair?

Tags: feature-request, badges

I've just found out about flair, here's mine:

[image: profile for Roc Martí at Programmers, Q&A for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development]


[profile for Roc Martí on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1399093.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1399093)

I like it! But I would like it even more if my Meta badges were shown in there!

I understand that [Meta reputation is derived from the main website](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation), but I don't think it would be a problem to show badges in the flair, the site one or the combined one. Of course there is the option of Meta flair, but I don't think anyone would ever use that.